# Transistor heating problem in slayer exciter circuit

Tags: transistors, heat, tesla-coil

i made [this project](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-a-Miniature-Tesla-Coil/) but it is not working and the transistor is heating up very fast, i couldn't find anything regarding this specific project but as far as i understood i should maybe use another transistor, what do you suggest?

Comment: Exactly which transistor are you using? http://www.analogzoo.com/2015/03/beware-the-p2n222a/

Answer (score 0):

Q1 will blow up. Veb, the reverse breakdown voltage between the base and emitter will be exceeded. Place a reverse diode or a LED across base-emitter. Remember that most silicon BJTs can only handle 6 to 8 volts reverse across base-emitter.

Comment: thanks but could you please explain better what i should do? i don't know electronics very good because i just started to "play" with it, maybe a circuit scheme would be helpful

Comment: @Er  pupis down .Get say a 1n4148 diode and connect across B.E. of your transister with the black line on the B.